# undefined method `class_attribute' for ActionController::ApiRendering:Module when using Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just upgraded to Rails 5. I am getting error in an app which was developed using Rails 4.2. I am getting the following error while running `rails c`.  What should I do?

> /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionview-5.0.0.beta1/lib/action_view/view_paths.rb:8:in `block in <module:ViewPaths>': undefined method`class_attribute' for ActionController::ApiRendering:Module (NoMethodError)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**How to upgrade from Rails 4.2 to Rails 5.0**

**1 - Update ruby** : 
Rails 5 now requires Ruby 2.2.2 or greater. I suggest installing the latest:

```
rbenv install 2.3.1

rvm install 2.3.1
```

**2 - Update your gem dependencies to Rails 5** :

Change Rails version in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '>= 5.0.0.rc2', '< 5.1'
```

**Update Rails dependencies:**

```
bundle update rails
```

You also might need to update some gems. Hopefully you have a nice test suite to rely on; this makes upgrading much smoother. So for each gem you have problems with, go to their documentation and check if they have any guidance for the upgrade.